# C nested switches: outer switch's case inside inner switch

Tags: c, language-design, interpreter, coroutine

I'm adding coroutine support to an interpreter I'm writing and I'd like to do something like the following:

```
typedef enum {
    bar_stuff,
    bar_other
    } Bar;

typedef enum {
    foo_error=-1,
    foo_none=0,
    foo_again
    } Foo_state;

Foo_state do_foo(Bar bar,Foo_state foo)
    {
    switch(foo)
        {
        case foo_none: //start
        switch(bar)
            {
            case bar_stuff:
                //do stuff
                return foo_none;
            case bar_other:
                //do other stuff
                return foo_again;
                case foo_again: //!! this doesn't work
                    /* edit: this is supposed to be a case of
                     *     switch(foo), not switch(bar)
                     */
                //do more other stuff
                return foo_none;
            default:
                //stuff
                return foo_none;
            }
        default:
            //fail
            return foo_error;
        }
    }
```

Obviously this dosn't work (I get duplicate case value, alternative is probably undefined behavior/segfault).  I could write switch(bar) as an if/else if/else chain, but I was hoping there was a better way.

I'm using gcc if that makes a difference.

#### Edit:

The following would work, but would be a PITA to maintain:

```
Foo_state do_foo2(Bar bar,Foo_state foo)
    {
    switch(foo)
        {
        case foo_none:  goto case_foo_none;
        case foo_again: goto case_foo_again;
        default:
            //fail
            return foo_error;
        }
    case_foo_none: //start
    switch(bar)
        {
        case bar_stuff:
            //do stuff
            return foo_none;
        case bar_other:
            //do other stuff
            return foo_again;
            case_foo_again:
            //do more other stuff
            return foo_none;
        default:
            //stuff
            return foo_none;
        }
    }
```

#### Edit 2:

Well, this doesn't seem to be yielding the aforementioned 'better way', so I'd like know if anyone foresees a problem with writing it like this:

```
Foo_state do_foo3(Bar bar,Foo_state foo)
    {
    switch(foo)
        {
        case foo_none: //start
        if(bar == bar_stuff)
            {
            printf("do stuff\n");
            return foo_none;
            }
        else if(bar == bar_other)
            {
            printf("do other stuff\n");
            return foo_again;
            case foo_again: //continue
            printf("do more other stuff\n");
            return foo_none;
            }
        else
            {
            printf("stuff\n");
            return foo_none;
            }
        default:
            //fail
            return foo_error;
        }
    }
```

The problem I see with this is missing a bar_* value (since there are several functions like this, and some of the enums have dozens of values), but I suppose a test script for that should work...

Comment: When you say you want "something like the following" and then post invalid code, what are we supposed to think you really want? If that code were valid, what would it do?

Comment: Yes, PITA is right ... why not draw out a state machine on paper, simplify it on paper, and then come up with proper names of the variables which would self-document this process at least to a degree?  You are representing a state with these variables. Why not use a single variable for state?

Comment: I posted a reference of how I meant it to work. (But I'm hoping to find a less ugly way of doing it.)

Comment: Seriously, draw a 3 x 3 table in Excel, list the stuff to be executed and the value to return. Block the conditions together. http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/02/K-map_6,8,9,10,11,12,13,14_anti-race.svg

You can take another shortcut with if(foo_again && bar_other) { ... } That should leave you with a single switch statement.

Comment: Possibly useful: http://blog.think-async.com/2009/08/secret-sauce-revealed.html (While some of that is C++-specific, the switch hack is the same in C and it shows how to factor out the "co-calls" from the individual logic.)

Comment: @Roger thanks, that's kind of what I'm trying to do. More specifically, I'm trying to apply this: http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/coroutines.html to a (group of) functions for recursivly evaluating a syntax tree.

Comment: The name of this question is somewhat confusing now - you should be more specific

Comment: Can you explain why `case foo_again` (or `case_foo_again` in `do_foo2`) lives inside the `switch (bar)` block at all?  In your examples, it's not sharing any code with other `switch (bar)` cases, so it's unclear what the point is for what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 6):

You can also just put { } inside each case: statement
without them the whole case stack is evaluated as a single unit, so no variables can be defined within one case:

But by putting

```
 case blah:
 {
  // do stuff
 }
 break;
```

You can put anythign you want inside the case statement.

Answer (score 4):

Hm ... use an equivalent of a Karnaugh Map to simplify the logic and do it all with

```
if (cond1 && cond2) {
  doX();
  return;
}
if (cond3 && cond4) {
  doY();
  return;
}
// Sometimes you can take shortcuts
if (cond5) {
   doZ();
} else {
   doW();
}
return;
```

This code is readable. Nested things are best avoided if possible.

Checking the simplest conditions first will make the function simpler.

IN YOUR CASE START WITH:

```
Foo_state do_foo2(Bar bar,Foo_state foo) {
  if (foo != foo_none && foo != foo_again) {
    return foo_error;
  }
  ...

  if (foo == foo_none) {
    ...
  }
  // Implicit Else
  ...
```

Comment: That doesn't do the same thing, if `(foo==foo_again)` I want it to resume after the `return foo_again;`.

Comment: @lpthnc: I agree with your approach...Sounds like a finite state machine that is being coded together using nested switch statements...but your approach is more cleaner and simpler!

Answer (score 1):

A simple fix would be to change the values in the bar_ enum so that they are unique with respect to the foo_ enum. That doesn't address the fact, however, that your code is confusing. Why would you look for a foo_ value inside of the bar_ switch statement? Syntactically, it is valid (as long as the values are unique) but its poor coding.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems that your code does this:

```
bar \ foo   foo_none                          foo_again                             other
bar_stuff   doStuff, return foo_none          do more other stuff, return foo_none  return foo_error
bar_other   do other stuff, return foo_again  do more other stuff, return foo_none  return foo_error
other       stuff, return foo_none            do more other stuff, return foo_none  return foo_error
```

This is what I meant by a Karnaugh Map. Now, here is the simplest implementation:

```
Foo_state do_foo2(Bar bar,Foo_state foo) {
  if (foo == foo_again) {
    // do more stuff
    return foo_none;
  }
  if (foo != foo_none) { // other
    return foo_error;
  }
  // foo_none
  if (bar == bar_stuff) {
    // do stuff
    return foo_none;
  }
  if (bar == bar_other) {
    // do other stuff
    return foo_again;
  }
  // At this point bar = other

  // stuff
  return foo_none;
}
```

I believe this does the same thing as your code, but does not use switches and gotos. You can fill out a table with the result, and you can also put both implementations through a unit tests to make sure they do the same thing for all inputs.